# Can a 3rd-level aegis add "improved damage" to the astral skin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

A 3rd-level aegis, with the astral skin, has 2×speed, 1×nimble, and 1×evasion, plus 5 customization points.

Can the aegis improve the astral skin with 1cp×darkvision, 2cp×brawn, and 2cp×improved damage, for a total of 5 customization points?

I correct the misunderstanding (I hope): yes 1,2and3 are customization point costs, sorry. My doubt is: improved damage is "in astral armor" and not in "astral skin", to have in "astral skin" you have to use customization points but in the "improved damage" says " it can be taken at 5th lev". This is my real question. However you answered me correct at the first time cause you list all customization required. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, that is correct.

At your level, the astral skin does indeed come with free customizations of evasion, nimble, and 2×speed, and you do indeed get 5 customization points. The customizations you have selected have the costs you list, and that does sum up to 5, so you can afford them. None of them have a level requirement that you’re failing. So yes, this all works.

Comment: we posts at the same time!